# Необособленная прямая речь

Tags: пунктуация

В одной книге встретил такой абзац. Удивило то, что прямая речь (или мысле-речь, выделена курсивом) не обособлена вообще никак. Так можно писать? По какому правилу?

Наконец, эта мука окончилась — Алису отвели в покои. Прислали служанку на случай, если что-то понадобится. *Мне ничего не нужно, — думала Алиса, — я зажмурюсь и просто исчезну.* Сомкнув веки, она тут же забылась.

Answer (score 0):

Автор свободен. Отказался от лишнего, ненужных Ему абзаца или кавычек, ввёл курсив, редкий приём в литературе. Он виновен, но он не виновен.

Comment: курсив всё-таки ввёл уже я